# How can I integrate Keycloak SSO with Php application?

Tags: php, laravel, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am very new to keycloak which is open source that provides authentication to our app.
I have my simple php app and I need to integrate the Keycloak SSO feature with my php app.

I did some research on google that keycloak does not provide any adapter to integrate with php app.
But I found an adapter on github Aatccama/keycloak-adapter-php.

This is repo link : [Keycloak php adapter](https://github.com/ataccama/keycloak-adapter-php)

But I did not understand how to use it.
Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any OpenId connect library you want to use Keycloak with PHP. Do a Google search on `openid connect php` and you will find a multitude of libraries and tutorials.

On your second question I suggest to delve into the Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/documentation) itself before you put any auth solution online.
A basic knowledge of DevOps is required so I suggest you also look into that topic for deploying and managing a server as Keycloak can be deployed in many ways depending on your own preferences.

You have a example to guide more with [sso-keycloak-php](https://github.com/firmanJS/sso-keycloak-php) repo.

Comment: What is openId stand for?

Comment: I found jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Comment: Are we can connect via openid or php adaptor?